# How to disable right click option given by youtube

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image: I want the options to be removed when user click right button]I have iframe in my website i want to disable options given by youtube...

```
<iframe style="width:30%" height="284" src="<?php echo $fetchorderdetails['video_links'] ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

This my iframe [image: I want to remove this options given by youtube]

Comment: You cannot change how an iframe's content behaves if it's on another domain.

Comment: target that popup element and add `display: none` css

Comment: @XenioGracias — How? They can't change YouTube's CSS.

Comment: You can only put something on top (z-index), but this will disable play function. If you want that then you will need to write video player and use your own video files.

Answer (score 0):

I you can't edit the dynamics content of an iframe.